# Команда git add

Tags: git

Подскажите, можно ли добавить файлы  опред. разрешения (например *.html) из текущей папки, без  подкаталогов? Что-то я так и не нашел решения.

Comment: `git add *.html`, не?

Comment: @TotalPusher, если есть подкаталоги с версированными файлами, то `git add` обработает и их.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, нет.

Comment: @TotalPusher, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add: "`git add Documentation/\*.txt` Adds content from all *.txt files under Documentation directory and its **subdirectories**"

Comment: @ГерманБорисов оьрати внимание на бэкслеш. Без него звёздочку интерполирует шелл, а он по умолчанию в подкаталоги не ходит

Comment: Причём это уточнение написано сразу под примером

Comment: @AlexyTex, на самом деле ответ зависит от того, раскрывает shell `*` в список сам, или передает git'у. Microsoft cmd.exe звездочку не раскрывает, и git будет обрабатывать с подкаталогами. bash же раскроет сам, и передаст в git не `*`, а подготовленный список без подкаталогов.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов согласен. Просто у меня в голове git и cmd никак не совмещаются

Comment: Автору наверное проще взять какой-нибудь git-bash или в следующий раз сразу уточнять про cmd

Comment: Пардон, не указал среду. Эмулятор консоли для винды ConEmu. При старте - {Shells::cmd}.
git add *.html обрабатывает подкаталоги, что иногда неудобно.
Если есть возможность выбрать файлы сторонней утилитой - подскажите

Comment: За целый день можно было бы уже и документацию прочитать. `git add :(glob)*.html` должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Однако документацию чего именно в данном случае?
Если бы я нашел сам, не стал бы тут ждать ответа

Comment: Добавил в ответ ссылку на документацию.

Comment: @Влад открываем доку по git-add. Нас интересует указание пути, т.е. `<pathspec>` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203 в конце раздела ссылка на глоссарий https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec. Вуаля

Comment: Ясно. но это перерыть кучу доков на инглише. В том же глоссарии перечислено все, а я не знал, что именно следует искать. А ведь вопрос не какой-то специфический, я был уверен, что кто-то уже знает решение

Answer (score 4):

Судя по документации и ответам на en.SO, единственный способ - перечислить файлы вручную или с помощью сторонней утилиты, например, `find` или даже shell'ом, если он раскрывает символ `*` сам (в bash это работает, в cmd - нет).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663402/how-to-git-add-non-recursively

**UPD**

По подсказке от @AlexyTen нашел в [документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) вот такой момент:

Параметр `--glob-pathspecs` (вставляется между git и командой, например `git --glob-pathspecs add *.html`) добавляет "магию" glob'а в обработку спецсимволов в пути. Того же эффекта можно добиться спецификатором ":(glob)"

К сожалению, для автора документации очевидно, что такое glob, и он не вдавался в подробности.

Судя по тому, что мне удалось нагуглить за 5 минут, glob - это консольная утилита, которая на заре unix использовалась для раскрытия спецсимволов в список файлов. Затем этот функционал был встроен в сам shell unix-подобных ОС.

Таким образом указание данного параметра или спецификатора заставляет git обрабатывать `*` так же как и стандартный unix shell, т.е. без подкатологов.

Comment: Если в ручную, то можно еще через git add -i